# Interface and generics with Java

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface defined in this way:

```
public interface GenericBo<T, PK extends Serializable> {
```

and another interface

```
public interface ServiceActivityBo<ServiceActivity, String> extends GenericBo<T, PK extends Serializable>
```

but I have an compilation error in the ServiceActivityBo when defined PK:
Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

How should be defined the ServiceActivityBo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define it like this instead:

```
public interface ServiceActivityBo extends GenericBo<ServiceActivity, String> {
```